# getting current tick data from metatrader5

Tags: python, android-livedata, forex, metatrader5

i have written this about three different times differently but i keep getting an empty dataframe. what have i overlooked? this code is part of a class.

```
import pytz
import MetaTrader5 as mt5
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

def tick_data(self):
    utc_time = pytz.timezone('UTC')
    noww = datetime.now(utc_time)
    date_ = noww - timedelta(days=8)date_from = date_.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    date_to = noww.date()
    ticks = mt5.copy_ticks_range(self.symbol, date_from, date_to, mt5.COPY_TICKS_ALL)
    mt5.shutdown()
    ticks_frame = pd.DataFrame(ticks)
    print(ticks_frame.head(10))
```

```
eurusd_data = PairData('EURUSD')
eurusd_data.tick_data()
```

the code below doesn't use class instance but is just about the same issue. i thought my translation of time was the issue so i just used dates and no class but it still gave me an empty dataframe. so what is the issue?

```
import pytz
import MetaTrader5 as mt5
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

def tick_data(symbol):
    symbol = mt5.symbol_select('EURGBP', True)
    if not symbol:print('please insert the correct symbol')
    utc_time = pytz.timezone('UTC')
    date_from = datetime(2023, 1, 10, tzinfo=utc_time)
    date_to = datetime(2023, 1, 18, tzinfo=utc_time)
    bars = mt5.copy_ticks_range(symbol, date_from, date_to, mt5.COPY_TICKS_ALL)
    b_frame = pd.DataFrame(bars)
    print(b_frame.head(17))
```

```
tick_data('EURGBP')
```

i need a dataframe but keep getting an empty one. I'd love it if the first code worked.

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It's a pity that MetaTrader5 is limited to Windows otherwise more people might be able to help you